# How to access Graphite RAW data in json or any other format?

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have used graphite-tcp to generate some mock data to grafana dashboard, but still it is not available in Grafana Dashboard. I have already updated dashboard.json in grafana. I'm getting success message in node js graphite-tcp while heating IP and PORT and metric plus Timestamp. Is there any way we can check graphite raw data ?

```
var graphite = require('graphite-tcp');

const graphiteConfiguration = {
    host: HOST,
    port: PORT,
    family: FAMILY,
    prefix: PREFIX,
    suffix: SUFFIX,
    verbose: false,
    interval: 60000,
    callback: (_error, metricsSent) => {
        console.log('Metrics sent\n'+ metricsSent)
    }
  }

var metricConf = graphite.createClient(graphiteConfiguration);
metricConf.add(metric.metricName, Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10)))
```

in callback I'm getting Metrics Sent Message as Success.

But no data is available in Grafana !!

Please help.

I was expecting correct Values and Data in Dashboard but nothing was available there.

Answer (score 0):

use whisper-dump.py on the .wsp files, or access graphite's api directly.